# Laravel 5 - Home Page Route

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5, routes

I have a route issue, I can't point `localhost/test/` into my index page of my site.

When I define a route like:

```
`Route::get("/",IndexController@index);`
```

`localhost/test/` would work fine , but also `localhost/test/admin`, `localhost/test/en` `localhost/test/foo` `localhost/test/undefined-route` and will load my index page of the site.

and beside when I have namespace Route like:

```
Route::group(['namespace'=>'Admin'],function(){

     Route::controller("admin"=>"AdminController");

})
```

If I type `localhost/test/foo/admin` everything works fine but when I write:
`localhost/test/admin` just my index page of the site.

I don't know whats wrong here, Route problem or `.htaccess` redirecting my and I'm not aware of it.

Sorry for code misspelling I just wrote what I recall from last night.

Note:: I have an index file in my root directory
my `.htaccess` file of my root directory is like below, and I replaced the `server.php` file of my root directory with my `index.php` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and my `.htaccess` file of my public directory is like default.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to Laravel 5.3 seems to Solved the Route Issue,

Answer (score 0):

why don't you run (from terminal):

```
php artisan serve
```

then test your project at: http://localhost:8000/ instead of: http://localhost/test/

or if you are using apache, add new virtual host

Comment: i tested it with Apache LogLevel rewrite:trace7 ,but i didnt get anything what causing this, ok i try it , thanks